# Android Phone > Wifi > Pc > Speakers

Tags: android, audio, microphone, voice

I would like to know how to develop an app/server. My android phone will record my voice when I speak and it will be sent to the PC and then played using the PC's speakers.

I think I need a media server running on the computer to receive my voice then play it back with an app already on the phone, using wifi protocol.

Would like to ask for some codes/steps on how to do this.

Thank you.
PS: Sorry guys, I need to use Android SDK or ADT something like that to do this.
And it will work like a microphone, when I speak it will play immediately.

Comment: Personally I would have the android app push the recording to an Amazon S3 bucket and then send a message to Amazon SQS that a recording is ready. Then the desktop app could subscribe to that SQS channel and pull down and play any media file as soon as a message is detected.

Comment: Another alternative to the SQS layer is a service called PubNub which is a service focused on broadcasting and subscribing to real time activity across devices and networks.

Comment: Define _"immediately"_. The recording part on the Android device is likely to introduce a bit of latency, which can be quite substantial (100 ms or more) in particular on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

For voice recording: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html
For sending audio via http: [how to send audio file from android client to servlet server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633083/how-to-send-audio-file-from-android-client-to-servlet-server)